# LateInitializationError: Field '_origin@101043362' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter-dependencies

**LateInitializationError: Field '_origin@101043362' has not been initialized**. am getting this error
as below, am new to coding

Error displayed when running the app:

[image]

### Below is the user page

```
import 'package:edgescope_app/MapUtils.dart';
import 'package:edgescope_app/pages/directions_.dart';
import 'package:edgescope_app/pages/reason_hold.dart';
import 'package:edgescope_app/pages/reason_return.dart';
import 'package:edgescope_app/pages/start_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:edgescope_app/model/user.dart';
import 'package:edgescope_app/pages/start_page.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';


class UserPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final User user;

  const UserPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.user,
  }) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
      Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(user.username),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(user.urlAvatar),
                radius: 80,
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 40),
              Text(
                user.username,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 28,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Order number: ',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),

                    Text(user.order,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                  ]
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Location: ',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),

                    Text(user.location,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                  ]
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Phone number: ',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),

                    Text(user.email,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                  ]
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 65),
              Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    RaisedButton.icon(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 4),
                      color: Colors.green,
                      icon: Icon(
                          Icons.play_circle_outline, color: Colors.white),
                      label: Text(
                        'Start',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (
                                BuildContext context) => new StartPage(user: user,)));
                      },),
                    RaisedButton.icon(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 4),
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.location_pin, color: Colors.white),
                      label: Text(
                        'Map',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (
                                BuildContext context) => new DirectionPage()));
                      },

                    ),
                    RaisedButton.icon(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 4),
                      color: Colors.amberAccent,
                      icon: Icon(
                          Icons.pause_circle_outline, color: Colors.white),
                      label: Text(
                        'Hold',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (
                                BuildContext context) => new ReasonHold()));
                      },
                    ),
                    RaisedButton.icon(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 4),
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.cancel_outlined, color: Colors.white),
                      label: Text(
                        'Return',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (
                                BuildContext context) => new ReasonReturn()));
                      },
                    ),
                  ]
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );

}
```

### Below is the start page

```
// ignore_for_file: unnecessary_null_comparison
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:edgescope_app/blocs/application_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:edgescope_app/model/user.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:edgescope_app/model/directions_model.dart';
import 'package:edgescope_app/model/directions_respository.dart';

class StartPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final User user;
  const StartPage({Key? key, required this.user}) : super(key: key);

   @override
  _StartPageState createState() => _StartPageState();
}

class _StartPageState extends State<StartPage> {
  static ApplicationBloc _applicationBloc = ApplicationBloc();

  static  CameraPosition _initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng (_applicationBloc.currentLocation.latitude,
        _applicationBloc.currentLocation.longitude),
    zoom: 14,
  );

  var locationMessage="";
  var clientLocation = "";
  var directionInfo ="";
  get dio => null;

  void getCurrentLocation() async{
    var position = await Geolocator
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    var lastPosition =await Geolocator.getLastKnownPosition();
    print(lastPosition);
    var lat = position.latitude;
    var long = position.longitude;
    print("$lat,$long");

    setState(() {
      locationMessage ="$lat,$long";
    });
  }
  void getClientLocation() {
  }

  late GoogleMapController _googleMapController;
  late Marker _origin;
  late Marker _destination;
  late Directions _info;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _googleMapController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final applicationBloc = Provider.of<ApplicationBloc>(context);


    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Start"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.place),
            onPressed: () {
             getCurrentLocation();
              getClientLocation();
            },
          ),
          if(_origin != locationMessage)
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () => _googleMapController.animateCamera(
                CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
                  CameraPosition(
                    target: _origin.position,
                    zoom: 14.5,
                    tilt: 50.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              icon: Icon(Icons.my_location),
            ),
          if (_destination != null)
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () => _googleMapController.animateCamera(
                CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
                  CameraPosition(
                    target: _destination.position,
                    zoom: 14.5,
                    tilt: 50.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              icon: Icon(Icons.person_pin_circle_outlined),
            )
        ],
      ),

      body: (applicationBloc.currentLocation == null)?
      Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),):
      ListView(
        children: [
         Column(children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 400.0,
                child: GoogleMap(
                  mapType: MapType.normal,
                  myLocationEnabled: true ,
                  zoomControlsEnabled: true,
                  initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition,
                  onMapCreated: (controller) => _googleMapController = controller,
                    markers: {
                      if (_origin != null) _origin,
                      if (_destination != null) _destination
                    },
                    polylines: {
                      if (_info != null)
                        Polyline(
                          polylineId: const PolylineId('overview_polyline'),
                          color: Colors.red,
                          width: 5,
                          points: _info.polylinePoints
                              .map((e) => LatLng(e.latitude, e.longitude))
                              .toList(),
                        ),
                    },
                    onLongPress: _addMarker,
                  ),
                ),
              if(_info != null)
                Positioned(
                  top: 20.0,
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 6.0,
                      horizontal: 12.0,
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.yellowAccent,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      boxShadow: const [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.black26,
                          offset: Offset(0, 2),
                          blurRadius: 6.0,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      '${_info.totalDistance}, ${_info.totalDuration}',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
               ]
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Text('Find Nearest',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Wrap(
              spacing: 8.0,
              children: [
                FilterChip(label: Text('Nearest Route'),
                  onSelected: (val) => applicationBloc.togglePlaceType('direction',val),
                  selected: applicationBloc.placetype =='direction',
                ),
                FilterChip(label: Text('Nearest Route'),
                  onSelected: (val) => applicationBloc.togglePlaceType('direction',val),
                  selected: applicationBloc.placetype =='direction',
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Wrap(
              spacing: 220.0,
              children: [
                FilterChip(label: Text('Accept'),
                  onSelected: (val) => applicationBloc.togglePlaceType('direction',val),
                  selected: applicationBloc.placetype =='direction',
                  backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                ),
                FilterChip(label: Text('Reject'),
                  onSelected: (val) => applicationBloc.togglePlaceType('direction',val),
                  selected: applicationBloc.placetype =='direction',
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  void _addMarker(LatLng pos) async {
    if (_origin == null || (_origin != null && _destination != null)) {
      // Origin is not set OR Origin/Destination are both set
      // Set origin
      setState(() {
        _origin = Marker(
          markerId: const MarkerId('origin'),
          infoWindow: const InfoWindow(title: 'Origin'),
          icon:
          BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueGreen),
          position: pos,
        );
        // Reset destination
        _destination = clientLocation as Marker;

        // Reset info
        _info = directionInfo as Directions;
      });
    } else {
      // Origin is already set
      // Set destination
      setState(() {
        _destination = Marker(
          markerId: const MarkerId('destination'),
          infoWindow: const InfoWindow(title: 'Destination'),
          icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueBlue),
          position: pos,
        );
      });

      // Get directions
      final directions = await DirectionsRepository(dio: dio)
          .getDirections(origin: _origin.position, destination: pos);
      setState(() => _info = directions!);
    }
  }


}
```

### Please assist

I have tried to look where the error is coming from but unfortunately am not getting it completely
is there away to clear this error please assist.

Comment: Where are you called UserPage? Are pass user as a parameter in UserPage class?

Comment: Yes I am passing the user as a parameter

Comment: I have a local Json that am calling from as below,
`class User {
  final String username;
  final String email;
  final String urlAvatar;
  final String location;
  final String order;
  

  const User({
    required this.username,
    required this.email,
    required this.urlAvatar,
    required this.location,
    required this.order,
  });

  static User fromJson(json) => User(
         location: json['location'],
        username: json['username'],
        email: json['email'],
         order: json['order'],
        urlAvatar: json['urlAvatar'],
      );
}
`

Comment: _applicationBloc.currentLocation where are you  pass  currentLocation on bloc?

Comment: am passing it from a geolocator with a change notifier as below
`import 'package:edgescope_app/services/geolocator_service.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class ApplicationBloc with ChangeNotifier{
  final geoLocatorService = GeoLocatorService();

  late Position currentLocation;

  ApplicationBloc(){
  SetCurrentLocation();
}

  get placetype => null;

  SetCurrentLocation() async{
    currentLocation = await geoLocatorService.getCurrentLocation();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  togglePlaceType(String s, bool val) {}
}`